# cmake cannot set RUNTIME_OUTPUT_LIBRARY for one target

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using cmake to build my c++ project, first I set all the runtime targets to go to a "bin" directory using this code

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

but I need a different output directory for some special targets, I tried using

```
set_target_properties(${special_target} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "special_path" )
```

but it's not working, the ${special_target} still goes to the bin directory, how to do this?

mcve:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
project(mcve)
add_executable(special_target special.cpp)
set_target_properties(special_target PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/someotherpath)
```

Comment: The syntax is `set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ....`. CMake should complain about your code. Doesn't it?
(cf. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html)

Comment: @kfunk yes, I missed the "PROPERTIES" while posting the question, thanks for reminding.

Comment: You should post a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least the way `special_target` is defined and also include at least the CMake output in your question. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @kfunk MWE is provided, thanks in advance : )

Comment: @matrix_space: Works for me. When compiling: `[100%] Linking CXX executable someotherpath/special_target`. Is your CMake too old maybe? CMake 3.9.1 here.